# Text to speech with my own voice android studio

Tags: android

I've tried creating an Android app with my voice but I failed. I'm wondering. How can I create an app with my own voice?

I know that I can do that with python library but the problem is that I didn't know how to set my voice in android app.

If anyone know please  tell me.

Comment: You'll need to elaborate what you mean by 'creating an Android app with my voice'. In general you should try to be as specific as you can when asking questions and mention what you've already tried.

Comment: You need to be clear with your questions.